# Persist entire view object

Tags: javascript

When the client calls the track method with a name of pageView, the following should occur:

Fields that should be persisted
If the view.type is = 'page', the entire view object should be persisted.
I wrote some code but it don't work correctly any ideas how to fix this ?

```
function pageView(data) {
    let view = {};

    if (view.type === 'page') {
        view = data;
    }
    return {
        view
    };
}

export default pageView;
```

Comment: Please give more details of what you try to accomplish

Comment: I'm trying to write page View event when it occurs it should check if view,type is page if statement is true then entire view object should be persisted.

Comment: What do you mean by "persisted"? Returned, saved, etc?

Comment: By persisted i mean saved

Comment: view is always {} as you set it in line 2. look at the `if` statement, maybe it should be `data.type === 'page'`?

Answer (score 1):

Condition `view.type === 'page'` is newer met because `view` is always `{}`

Comment: Maybe you wanted to check if data.type === 'page' ? Or view variable you are referring to should be something different (not local)? Can you provide info on which framework are you using?